# Good way to save multiple elements in one SQL Comlumn?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm modelling MySQL database for an website.

I'm now making **'people'** table, and deciding what **columns** needed.

a **person** has a **name** column, 
and I want to add **alias** column, which contains the names in various conventions.

for example, a person whose name is *'Micheal Jackson'* may have **aliases** like '*M. Jackson*', 
*'Jackson, M'*, or *'M.J.'*.

Anyway, each person can have different number of aliases, then What **data type** could be rational?

Make *alias* field as a **Varchar**, and put every aliases in it, and split them in PHP?

or make aliases **dynamically** from *name* in PHP? instead of putting it in DB?

I'm waiting for good recommendations, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a new table and call it `aliases`. This table should have a Many-To-One relation with your table `people`.

[image: Tables relation]

The table `aliases` should have a foreign key to the parent table `persons` (i.e. have a column `aliases.personId` which references `people.personId`)

Then to retrieve the data use `Joins`.

references:

[Cardinality (data modeling)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_%28data_modeling%29)

[Foreign key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)

[Join (SQL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

and lastly and most importantly [Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Answer (score 4):

The normalized way of doing this would be to have a separate aliases table with a person ID field and an alias field, and make a many to one relationship. Another way would be to have as you say, a `VARCHAR` field with all aliases and split them in PHP. If you never need to search for the alias, this should work, but the normalized version is a lot cleaner.

Comment: +1: Denormalized is a performance consideration *when there's a performance issue*, not before.

Comment: How you will typically use the values should also factor into your decision.

Answer (score 1):

it's probably best to use another table for alias but there is another way if you want to use one table

separate name and alias with # and put them in one column

Micheal Jackson#M.Jackson

in the php code you can use explode to get name and alias

```
$fullname = "Micheal Jackson#M.Jackson";

$each = explode('#' , $fullname );
$each[0];//Micheal Jackson
$each[1];//M.Jackson
```